# Form validation via jQuery.post with .val() returning 'null' error

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I'm building a login form that will validate the login against a database, then if successful pass the user to a secure page.

I have verified that my SQL is correct and based on the examples that I borrowed code from, my submit form should be correct also. In fact, the [sample code](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/04/ajax-login-validation-php-jquery.html) works properly on my server, which suggests a DOM error. This is a stripped-down version of what I'm running:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#login_form").submit(function() {
        jQuery("#msgbox").removeClass()
                         .addClass('messagebox')
                         .text('verifying')
                         .fadeIn(1000);

        jQuery.post("inc/ajax_login.php", {
            user_name: $('#username').val(),
            password: $('#password').val()
        }, function(data) {
            if (data == 'yes') { /* ... */
            }
            else { /* ... */
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});​
</script>
```

The form runs thus, some lines further down the page:

```
<form action="" id="login_form" method="POST">
  <input type="text"     name="username" id="username" value="username" />
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="password" /><br />
  <input type="hidden"   name="homeDir"  id="homeDir"  value=""         /> <span id="msgbox"></span> <br />
  <input type="submit"   name="Submit"    id="submit"    value="ENTER" class="submit"/>
</form>
```

However, JS throws an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of null."

I'm missing something here. Given that `.post` is not called until the form is submitted (and the error does not trigger until the form is submitted), why would `val()` be called against a null value? The form would be populated by then.

Also, I'm living on a PHP4.4.9 server. To the best of my understanding this is not a JSON call (therefore PHP5), but I'll freely admit I'm in over my head here. Webdev was a past life for me and was never my strong suit.

Comment: you are calling `val()` on `#username` and `#password` , do these DOM elements exist when the `$.post` call is made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were trying to call `val()` on a non-jquery object. When you use `jQuery.noConflict` mode '$' will be undefined. Try wrapping your jquery code like this...

See jQuery.noConflict doc - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/
Various methods to use jQuery.noConflict - http://zenverse.net/jquery-how-to-fix-the-is-not-a-function-error-using-noconflict/

```
<script>

jQuery.noConflict();

(function($) { 
    $("#login_form").submit(function()
    {
        $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('verifying').fadeIn(1000);

        $.post("inc/ajax_login.php", {
            user_name: $('#username').val(),
            password: $('#password').val()
        }, function(data) {
          if(data=='yes') {/* ... */}
          else {/* ... */}
        });

        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

Comment: Missing the `jQuery(function($)` killed me for a bit (self-labeled noob) but once I got that, it worked like a dream. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also

```
<script>

jQuery.noConflict();


jQuery("#login_form").submit(function()
{
    jQuery("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('verifying').fadeIn(1000);

    jQuery.post("inc/ajax_login.php", {
        user_name: jQuery('#username').val(),
        password: jQuery('#password').val()
    }, function(data) {
      if(data=='yes') {/* ... */}
      else {/* ... */}
    });

    return false;
});

</script>
```